# Postman sending in CSV data as a payload to update monitor

Tags: postman, monitor, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

We would like to store new CSV data in a monitor for every single iteration, as a means to test a dataset of over 80,000 rows. The end result would be that every time the monitor executes it has a new dataset to test that was extracted from an external file and sent in as an update via Postman API. Is this possible? Can't seem to find a way to update monitor values.

```
  var url = "https://api.getpostman.com/monitors/" + monitorId + "/run";
  var options = {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "X-Api-Key": apiKey,
      "Content-Type": "text/csv" // Change the content type header to plain text
    },
    payload: csv
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
```

Ran this script hoping it would run the specified monitor with the rows of data included in the CSV string.